# How to redirect user from one community to another using Login Flow without needed to re-authenticate?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, lightning-community, redirect, loginflow

How do I go about creating a Login Flow that redirects a user from one community to another without needing to re-authenticate?

We are beginning to roll out an updated community, and before upgrading everyone to it we wanted to perform a pilot test. The idea was to instead of requiring users to change the URL they navigate to, that a Login Flow could be used to redirect a user from the older community to the new one. However, when this is done it appears that the user is then asked to re-login to the new community instead of it just automatically logging them in.

Is there a way to bypass this need to login a second time? It really makes for a poor user experience as I don't want these users to update the URL they are navigating to and I also don't want them to re-login again.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you're looking for is SSO with salesforce as both the SP and IP. I've never tried it within the same org however. Here is some info that you can try to use:

- [Salesforce to Salesforce SSO](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_examples_sf2sf.htm)
- [SSO in communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_auth_configure_saml.htm&type=5)

In theory, you set up SSO, Then you enable your community to use SSO pointing to Salesforce as the IP, then you create a login flow that redirects some subset of your users to the sso endpoint for the second community which should reach back to salesforce as the IP and log in.

Again this is all theoretical, I have no idea if it will actually work.

Comment: I have tried to do this but I have been unsuccessful setting this up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if both communities are on the same domain then users can move inbetween then. In this case, I have added my community to the same domain and changed the path so they are still different. This got me around the issue.